# JMeter - How long should I set the ramp up period for 500 users over the space of 1 hour

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to test an application can handle 500 users over the space on 1 hour.  How long should I set the ramp up period for the specified amount of time and users?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. There are no "strict" rules, no recommendations either.

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

So you can use 500 as ramp-up so all 500 users will be online in 500 seconds.

Other option is to set ramp-up period for 1st 30 minutes and next 30 minutes keep the load of 500 users.

The idea is to add users **gradually** so you could correlate increasing load with other metrics and KPIs like response time, number of transactions per second, number of errors, etc. so you could state where is the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), where is the first [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), etc.

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)

Comment: The Stepping Load Ramp-Up, is really something, Thanks for sharing, is there a way to have each thread start after a random delay? or should add the 100 thread manually to the thread schedule?

Comment: I wouldn't go for random arrivals as I believe that tests need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) and "randomness" and "repeatability" are mutually exclusive terms.

Answer (score 0):

The ramp-up period, Is the time needed to start all the threads defined.

So, If you add 3600 with 500 Thread, This will mean a new thread will be launched every 7.2 seoconds, And the last one will start after 1h ( 3600 seconds)

If this is what you want, you can set Ramp up to 3600.

quote from official [doc](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun.